# laravel spatie logs package set which field has been modified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have installed laravel spatie package for user logs, when any model will be updated i want to set which field has been modified in properties array i have tried like

i have included this on my model

```
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;
use LogsActivity;

protected static $logName = 'Posts';
protected static $logOnlyDirty = true;
```

in database i am getting row like

[image]

please let me know about other inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define which attributes it logs. Here is an example from the docs:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity; 
class NewsItem extends Model {
    use LogsActivity;
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'text'];
    protected static $logAttributes = ['name', 'text']; 
}
```

You can also set the `$logFillable` property to `true` to log all attributes defined in the models `$fillable` property.

Read the section here on [model events](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-activitylog/v2/advanced-usage/logging-model-events).